# How to make expandable (stretchable) action for cell as in mail app iOS9 Swift/obj-C

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Want to make, for example 3 actions for cell ("More", "Flag", "Delete"), and last must activate, if:

1) after opening action list, swipe the cell again in the same direction

2) when opening the action list by swipe, but swipe is continued

[image after first swipe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZuTp.png),

[image of second swipe pointer is near of the left screen edge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VcaKn.png)

Comment: Try a stackView, add your 3 actions + action list and then unhide them with animation on swipe; you need to use a gesture recogniser. Make sure you attach gesture recognisers to you actions in your stackView.

Comment: As a general rule, post code for an existing implementation and specify where you're having the problem. This question is something best left for researching yourself. for example, the first hit for "cocoapods tableview cell" is this https://cocoapods.org/pods/SWTableViewCell. clone it, look at its implementation and you'll be able to go from there possibly.

Comment: @user3069232, i do want use default actions for cells in UITableViews, cause i don`t think that apple official app uses some custom actions.. @ Louis Tur, about SWTable, thanx, i`ll check it, and abt code, i did`t  post it, cause i don`t have errors in it, i just want to implement described feature..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the only one way to do it as i wish, is to do it by my self or use third party solutions, as [mentioned](http://cocoapods.org/pods/SWTableViewCell) @Louis Tur or [this solution](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/afmslidingcell). But the best way for now for me is to make it by my self, cause it very specified task. Apple does`t even provide possibility to insert a logo in action (solution with pattern image is not considered)